# How can I use the workbench engine on a headless server?

Tags: rendering, workbench-render-engine

I'd like to use the workbench engine on a remote headless server (linux). However, blender crashes giving me the following error:

```
Unable to open a display
```

Is this even possible?

PS: Please excuse the rather meaningless tag. However, neither headless, workbench or server exist as tags.

Comment: Both Workbench and EEVEE require GPUs for rendering, does your machine have a graphics card?

Comment: Yes it does. I also tested EEVEE. However, It gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, it is apparently not possible to render on a headless server, when using the Workbench or the EEVEE engine:

[see dicussion here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-2-8-unable-to-open-a-display-by-the-rendering-on-the-background-eevee/1436/19)